# How to mock dynamic values in snapshot tests?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, snapshot

I have to snapshot tests:

1. I create snapshot from router page with custom routers(guards for logged in users) and every time i run this test i have different generated key.
2. I have new Date() in date picker, how do i mock that?
   Reassign global.Date doesn't work for me
  1.

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ isAllowed, ...props }) => (isAllowed
  ? <Route {...props} />
  : <Redirect to="/login" />);

const LoginProtectedRoute = ({ isAllowed, ...props }) => (isAllowed
  ? <Route {...props} />
  : <Redirect to="/" />);

const WebClient = (props: any) => {
  const { userTokenController } = props;
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <ProtectedRoute
            exact
            path="/"
            component={HomePage}
            isAllowed={UserTokenRepo().getUserAuth(userTokenController)}
          />
          {/* <Route path="/login" component={Login} /> */}
          <LoginProtectedRoute
            path="/login"
            component={Login}
            isAllowed={!UserTokenRepo().getUserAuth(userTokenController)}
          />
          <ProtectedRoute
            path="/ResourceManagement"
            component={ResourceManagement}
            isAllowed={UserTokenRepo().getUserAuth(userTokenController)}
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

```
                        "goForward": [Function],
                        "length": 1,
                        "listen": [Function],
                        "location": Object {
                          "hash": "",
    -                     "key": "gsde51",
    +                     "key": "q67i5b",
                          "pathname": "/login",
                          "search": "",
                          "state": undefined,
                        },
```

2. ```
                   <Calendar readOnlyInput view="month" dateFormat="mm/yy" value={startDate} onChange={this.handleChange} yearNavigator yearRange="2010:2030" />
   ```

```
    -                   value={2019-09-12T11:16:56.134Z}
    +                   value={2019-09-12T13:31:32.598Z}
```

Answer (score 0):

Decouple the real value from the actual snapshot test.

Pulled shamelessly from [this medium article](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/jest-snapshot-testing-with-dates-and-times-f3badb8f1d87)..

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import moment from 'moment-timezone';


it('renders without crashing', () => {
  moment.tz.setDefault('EST');
  let props = {
    currentDay: moment("2017-09-15 09:30:00").format("MMM Do YYYY h:mm:ss a")
  };

  const tree = renderer.create(<App {...props} />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: the point is, we don’t pass date in props, this is default state.

Comment: So what I meant by the decoupling comment was, by your own description, the calendar component is tightly coupled to the rest of the application. As you have found, this makes it a difficult component to test.